# I want to make a Physics Calculator (Kinematics and Projectiles), but I don't know how to structure it. What should I do?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a physics calculator where you enter a variable that you are looking for and then provide all of the other variables that you know. (i.e., you are looking for velocity at t = 5 seconds, and you have vnaught and acceleration) The calculator will have most kinematics and (maybe) projectile equations built in, such as V = at or Vf^2 = Vo^2 + 2a(X - Xo). But, I have no idea how I should structure it.

A friend recommended trying binary expression trees, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to approach this. Also, how can I implement all of the physics equations in? Through JSON?

```
public class Node {

    // Nodes used in the algebraic expression trees
    public Node(char symbol, ArrayList<ExpressionTree> equations) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.equations = equations;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
    // Nodes have a set of equations associated with them to calculate their value from their children 
    public double calculateValue() {
        for (ExpressionTree eq : equations) {
            try { 
                this.value = eq.calculateInOrder(eq.root);
                System.out.println(this.symbol + "'s value is: " + this.value);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Missing variables!");
            }
        }
        return this.value;
    }
}

public class ExpressionTree {
    // Constructs a tree and returns a single node that has children nodes who also have children nodes... etc.
    public Node constructTree(char postfix[]) {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        Node n, n1, n2;

        for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length; i++) { 
            if (!isOperator(postfix[i])) { 
                n = new Node(postfix[i]); 
                stack.push(n); // If operand, simply push into stack
            } else // If operator:
            { 
                n = new Node(postfix[i]); 

                // Pop two top nodes (these will be the two operands for the operation)
                n1 = stack.pop();
                n2 = stack.pop(); 

                // Make them children of this node
                n.right = n1; 
                n.left = n2; 

                // Add the node back to the stack. This node keeps its children in the stack.
                stack.push(n); 
            } 

        } 

        n = stack.pop(); // STACK IS NOW EMPTY. N IS THE LAST VALUE FROM STACK, A SINGLE ROOT NODE WITH CHILDREN (with more children).

        this.root = n; // Saves root for this tree instance
        return n; 
    }
    // Goes through each operation (infix)
    public double calculateInOrder(Node n) {
        if (n.left == null && n.right == null) {
            return n.value;
        }

        double leftsum = calculateInOrder(n.left);
        double rightsum = calculateInOrder(n.right);

        if (n.symbol == '^') {
            return Math.pow(leftsum, rightsum);
        } else if (n.symbol == '*') {
            return leftsum * rightsum;
        } else if (n.symbol == '/') {
            return leftsum / rightsum;
        } else if (n.symbol == '+') {
            return leftsum + rightsum;
        } else if (n.symbol == '-') {
            return leftsum - rightsum;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot calculate without two operands and an operator!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using binary expression trees that model physics equations, and I have implemented code to calculate the value of the root of the trees if all other values are known. I'm not sure how to make trees that share specific nodes yet (like acceleration being in multiple trees), which is important for solving physics problems that require multiple calculations. Should I scrap the entire expression tree thing? How do I approach this?

I'm sorry for posting this much code, and I know this is a really vague question. I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction so that I can figure out how to structure this. I know there are other physics calculators on the internet, but I have no idea how they are coded, and I'm want to write this myself to work on my coding skills. Thanks!

Comment: I like this question well enough, but it _does_ sound pretty broad, as you acknowledge. You could try to remove the broad language, though it might be tricky. Something like "What algorithms are suitable for X" would be more precise, though I'm not sure what X is. "What algorithms are suitable for parsing and calculating mathematical expressions?" I'm not in the field.

Comment: @DavidS, even those questions might be a little too opinion based. Additionally, there is a lot of existing info on parsing expressions. OP, I would encourage you to think about: is your question about implementing a physics calculator, or is it about implementing expression parsing? In the first case, you'll need to start by deciding whether it solves arbitrary equations, or only the ones it has built in - the latter being, much, much simpler, and not requiring general expression parsing. In the latter case, you should look at existing questions first, and come back with specific issues :)

Comment: Also, OP: if when you have an idea of what the limitations of your calculator will be, you would like feedback on how to structure the classes and functionality of your code, you should definitely consider posting on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is dedicated to exactly that sort of thing